# Hilbert space on convergence

Tags: functional-analysis

**Any hint** how I could construct a sequence of unit vectors in a Hilbert space $H$ that converges weakly to a vector with norm less than 1.

Answer (score 4):

Take $l_2$ as an example, then the standard unit vectors $e_n$ converge
to zero weakly.

Here is a slightly less trivial example, choose any $y \in l_2$ such that $\|y\| <1$. Now define $y_n$ to be the same as $y$ except the $n$th entry is
$\sqrt{1-\sum_{k \neq n} y(k)^2}$. Then $\|y_n\| =1$ and for any $\phi \in l_2$ we have
$| \langle \phi, y_n-y\rangle | = |\phi(n)| |\sqrt{1-\sum_{k \neq n} y(k)^2}-y(n)| \le 2|\phi(n)|$, hence $\langle \phi, y_n\rangle \to \langle \phi, y\rangle$.

Comment: Yea! I understand it but it doesn't give me the required unit vectors.

Comment: What do you mean, the vectors $e_n$ are unit vectors and they converge to $0$ which has norm less than one????

Comment: But the question is for a convergence to a non zero vector with norm less than 1. I used the hint by adding the vector on the $e_{n}$ and yes the weak convergence is true. But the obtained sequence is not unit vectors.

Comment: Where do the words non zero appear??? It is unreasonable to expect folks to guess what you are really asking :-).

Comment: I added an example that will converge to any $y $ of your choosing in the unit ball :-).

Comment: Thanks @Esmath.